# can't find out how to use thread pools?

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I have to modify a `BankServer` java class for a project, that uses a Thread and I need to replace it with a `thread pool`. But the tutorials for thread pools are extremely confusing and none specify how to just make a thread pool.
for reference heres the thing I'm modifying

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{  ArrayList accountList;
  final int ACCOUNTS_LENGTH = 10;
  Bank bank = new Bank(ACCOUNTS_LENGTH);
  final int SBAP_PORT = 8888;
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SBAP_PORT);
  System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

  while (true)
  {
     Socket s = server.accept();
     System.out.println("Client connected.");
     BankService service = new BankService(s, bank);
     Thread t = new Thread(service);
     t.start();
  }
```

I don't need to do any fancy stuff just change `thread` t to `thread pool` but if theres a simple class called that I can't find it

Comment: Did you try looking at ExecutorService?

Answer (score 0):

### What you are looking for is ExecutorService

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 
public class ScheduledRunnable
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final int numTasks = 10;
        final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
        {
            ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable(i), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
 
    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        private int id;
        private int numRuns;
 
        private MyRunnable(final int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.numRuns = 0;
        }
 
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            this.numRuns += 1;
            System.out.format("%d - %d\n", this.id, this.numRuns);
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses the `ScheduleExecutorService` there are many more various implementations that do different things for different situations.

The `ExecutorService` was added to the JDK in 2004 with 1.5 specifically solve a fairly complex but common problem elegantly with very little code.

Answer (score 0):

It is too easy if you search and read some example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ArrayList accountList;
  final int ACCOUNTS_LENGTH = 10;
  Bank bank = new Bank(ACCOUNTS_LENGTH);
  final int SBAP_PORT = 8888;
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SBAP_PORT);
  System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREAD);

  while (BREAK_CONDITION) {
     Socket s = server.accept();
     System.out.println("Client connected.");
     BankService service = new BankService(s, bank);
     executor.execute(service);
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }
}
```

see also : [Thread Pools](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html) and [Java Thread Pool Example using Executors and ThreadPoolExecutor](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html)

Answer (score 0):

A ThreadPool is just a group of Worker Threads. Worker Threads are threads that can be reused.
Typically, when a Thread has finished processing the code inside of it, there is no way of restarting it. This is why we use worker threads. (so we dont need to create new thread objects for tasks that might not be running for that long)

ExecutorService provides you with different kinds of ThreadPools. Here are some of their basic ones:

```
Executor.newFixedThreadPool(50); //create Thread Pool with 50 worker threads
Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor(); //creates 1 worker thread
Executor.newCachedThreadPool(); //reuses already existing worker threads, but creates them as needed
```

An example of using one:

```
class App {
     private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          executor.execute(mycode); //instead of creating new thread and adding it, then starting
     }

     private Runnable mycode = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

          }
     };
}
```